# Plotting histograms with pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to plot feature distributions per label value for a ML project, but I'm not getting the plot I want.

I'm doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.randn(1000)
x2 = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randint(0,2,size=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':x1, 'x2':x2, 'y': y})

axes = df.hist(['x1', 'x2'], by='y', bins=10, layout=(2,2), figsize=(6,6))
```

which gives me:

[image]

But what I really need is a separate subplot for x1 and x2, showing the distributions of the values for the 0/1 label on the same plot. How could I do that?

Comment: @BigBen Let me try in seaborn - I had not thought about that.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there's not built in support in Pandas to do that exactly, however, you can achieve your desired result as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.randn(1000)
x2 = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randint(0,2,size=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':x1, 'x2':x2, 'y': y})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (9,4))

n_bins = 15
cols = ['x1', 'x2']


for i, col in enumerate(cols):
    # So your histograms share bins for each class
    bins = np.linspace(df[col].min(), df[col].max(), n_bins)
    plot_style = dict(bins = bins, alpha = 0.5, grid = False, edgecolor='k',)
    df[df['y']==1][col].hist(ax=ax[i], label = '1', **plot_style)
    df[df['y']==0][col].hist(ax=ax[i], label ='0', **plot_style)
    ax[i].set_title(col)
    ax[i].legend()
fig.tight_layout()
```

Which creates the following figure
[image]

Comment: @Frank, happy to help! Hope you caught my last edit in time however, apparently I was struggling to copy-paste accurately today

Answer (score 2):

Using [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) and `melt`ing first:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.displot(df.melt(id_vars='y'), x='value', col='variable', hue='y', bins=10)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: On 10k datapoints, with more features, this seems very slow? Seaborn is churning forever...

Comment: 16 features total - adding `bins` seems to have fixed it. However, the graph is hard to read, being all 16 features on one row :-)

Comment: Use the `col_wrap` parameter, e.g. `col_wrap=4`

Comment: BigBen, I might choose the other answer as The answer, just because it's not using seaborn, so I feel it's more "generic". But I like this answer with seaborn, and it works great.